# How to send data received from laravel controller to another page through ajax fetch API response

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade, fetch-api

I'm trying to send data received from controller to another page through JavaScript fetch API. how can I passes this data

```js
$(document).on('click', '#edit-property', function () {
  var data = $(this).data('info');
  fetch('/property/' + data)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        response.json().then(property => {
          console.log(property);
          window.location.href = "/property-details";
        })
      } else {
        console.error(' Reponse serveur : ' + response.status);
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the data as params in your url as you redirect to the page you are sending the data to.

```
    response.json().then(property => {

      window.location.href = "/property-details?property="+property ;

    })
```

Then here is the controller method retrieving data attached to the url:

**MyDataController.php**

```
public function getRequestParams(Request $request)
{
    $property = request()->property;
    return view('display_property')->with('property', $property));
}
```